# Knex.js for query as one query

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Can this be done as one query so there is not multiple request to the DB with the loop? Im trying to get each cameras last photo if any.

```
  async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
  }

 let cameras = await knex({ cameras: "device_manager_camera" })
    .select()
    .where("owner_id", 13);

  const start = async () => {
    let report = [];
    asyncForEach(cameras, async camera => {
      let photo = await knex({ photos: "device_manager_photo" })
        .where("camera_id", camera.id)
        .first();
      if (photo) {
        report[camera.name] = photo.timestamp;
      } else {
        report[camera.name] = "never";
      }
    });
    console.log(report);
  };

  start();
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend you to write your SQL query in plain SQL and it would be much easier to translate it to `knex` commands.

As for your request, I've come up with this query which returns the array of `[{ camera_id, timestamp }]`. It selects cameras of the owner with id 13 and joins this to max timestamps grouped query from table `photos`.

```
select
  c.name,
  coalesce(t.timestamp::text, 'never') as timestamp
from
  cameras as c
left join (
  select
    p.camera_id,
    max(p.timestamp) as timestamp
  from
    photos as p
  group by
    camera_id
) as t on t.camera_id = c.id
where
  c.owner_id = 13;
```

Correct your table names and columns if necessary.

Bonus style points. I'd not recommend using `timestamp` as a column name. It is a reserved column in some databases and it might need quotes around it to explicitly specify it as a column in your query, which might be annoying.